# Configuring Role Templates Mapping for Elasticsearch with OIDC Authentication Based on User Groups

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I configure Role templates mapping for Elasticsearch with OIDC authentication in such a way that user groups (e.g., "Projects AAA" and "Projects BBB") are mapped to corresponding roles (in this case, "aaa" and "bbb")?

I would like to know how to properly set up this mapping logic to automatically assign roles based on groups during OIDC authentication.